# Firebug - Finding HTML file behind code

Tags: firebug, firebug1.5

I have seen my question asked on several forums with no clear answers.

When viewing HTML code in the left pane and I spot the code that needs editing I cannot find the file that contains this code so I can make the necessary changes. Is it possible to find the path of the HTML file, or is the HTML feature of firebug just for entertainment? :)

Thanks guys!

Jim

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not find the path where the file is located, in many cases it will be on a server and not your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you see in firefox is interpreted as DOM.
Right click and click inspect on the part you interested and make modification to the DOM.
There is no way you can have access to the file path, which server manages.
For example, in php there is no html file but *.php file which would be translated to HTML by server and sent to client.